# Chaining scopes with joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, outer-join

these two scopes don't seem to be chainable

```
scope :approved, ->{ with_stage(:approved)}
```

which in sql is

```
WHERE (pages.stage & 4 <> 0)
```

and

```
scope :with_galleries, ->{ joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN galleries ON galleries.galleriable_type = 'Brand' AND galleries.galleriable_id = page.brand_id").where("galleries.id is NOT NULL") }
```

this scope should give only the pages that have galleries (each page has one brand and each brand can have many galleries)

if I chain the :`with_galleries`, it seems that the rest of the conditions on `pages` table is lost

Am I doing the `joins` wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get a more useful result if you let ActiveRecord do more of the heavy lifting for you. In particular, if you've set up associations properly, you should be able to write the following instead:

`scope :with_galleries, joins(brand: :galleries)`

... which would yield a properly chainable scope.

That would depend on two associations, one from your page model to the brand:

'belongs_to :brand'

and one from the brand to the galleries::

`has_many :galleries, as: :galleriable`

I'm inferring your model setup from the query that you've written, so I may have guessed wrong. But the basic principle here is to declare your associations and let ActiveRecord construct queries (unless your query is something very unusual, which yours is not -- you're just filtering depending on whether there are associated records, a common operation).

Comment: thanks! where can I read about the joins(brand: :galleries) syntax?

Comment: Ha! Actually, the syntax as I wrote it above looks funny to me, as I'm more used to the equivalent but older hash-rocket style: `joins(:brand => :galleries)`. You can read about it in the [Active Record Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). Search for "Joining Nested Associations".

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the second scope using Arel. The simplest approach is to craft the full SQL statement you want the second scope to represent, and then paste it into http://www.scuttle.io/